# Создание полей для ввода от выбранного элемента

Tags: javascript

Есть простой список `select` с 3-мя пунктами:

```
1
2
3
```

Если выбрал 1й пункт из `drop down list` то ниже `<br/><br/>`
появился один textbox, если выбрал 2й то тоже самое, но если выбрал 3й то появились 3 подряд textbox, как это сделать, что-то не понимаю(( как-то через `.js` реализовать? Такое динамическое изменение..

```
function SelectedItemFromDropDownListToBlock(e)
    {
        var selOpt = document.getElementById("ItemNameFromDropDownList");
        var result=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if(result>0)
        {
            var selectedItem=e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            ItemNameFromDropDownList.innerHTML=selectedItem;
        }
    }
```

//здесть jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectOptions', function()
        {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $('.tt').hide();
            if (id == '3')
            {
                $('.tt').show()
            }
            else
                {
                $('.textbox_' + id).show()
            }
        })

<select id="selectOptions" name="selectOptions">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Выбрать из списка</option>
    <option value="1">Первый</option>
    <option value="2">Второй</option>
    <option value="3">Третий</option>
</select>


<div class="alltextbox">
    <div class="tt textbox_1"><input type="text" name="textbox1" placeholder="textbox 1"></div>
    <div class="tt textbox_2"><input type="text" name="textbox2" placeholder="textbox 2"></div>
    <div class="tt textbox_3"><input type="text" name="textbox3"  placeholder="textbox 3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ar = ["Десять","Двадцать","Тридцать"];

$(document).on('change', '#my_select', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).val();
  var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $('.label').remove();
  $('.tt').hide();
  if (id == '3') {
    $.each($('#my_select').find('option'),function(key,value){
      //$('.textbox_' + key).prepend('<label class="label">' + $(this).text() + '</label>');
      $('.textbox_' + key).prepend('<label class="label">' + ar[key-1] + '</label>');
    })
    $('.tt').show();
  } else {
    $('.textbox_' + id).prepend('<label class="label">' + text + '</label>');
    $('.textbox_' + id).show();
  }
})
```

```css
.tt {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select" name="my_select">
  <option value="">Выберите пункт</option>
  <option value="1">Один</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
</select>

<div class="alltextbox">
  <div class="tt textbox_1"><input type="text" name="textbox1" placeholder="textbox 1"></div>
  <div class="tt textbox_2"><input type="text" name="textbox2" placeholder="textbox 2"></div>
  <div class="tt textbox_3"><input type="text" name="textbox3"  placeholder="textbox 3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду не сами слова textbox1 а поле для ввода т.наз. textbox(`input type="text">`)

Comment: Изменил в ответе `textbox` на `input type="text"`

Comment: А для чего `'change'` ? Просто скрипт вставил и не функционирует почему-то (((

Comment: Мой пример сделан с применением `jquery.js`. `change` - это событие изменения активного элемента `select`

Comment: Я понимаю, да, что с jquery.....:-(

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: у меня яваскрипт работает хорошо, я выбрал из списка и ниже показался тот пункт, в лейбл, который я выбрал, но в плюс мне нужно еще и чтобы нужно кол-ство полей было для каждого выбранного пункта..в вопросе добавлю скрипт и список

Comment: я думаю я могу вам помочь, но сейчас я запутался) есть `select` от выбора которого зависит определенный перечень полей для ввода, так? Или вам нужен перечень статей?

Comment: Мне нужно так: я из списка выбрал, к примеру, первый - появился 1 поле для ввода(textbox), и слева от этого поля для ввода, надпись, которую я выбрал. Выбрал второй, аналогичная ситуация, но если выбрал третий пункт из списка, то появились целых 3 поля для ввода
Сделайте пожалуйста через `selectOptions` :-)

Comment: Я взял чистый php файл и туда вставил вот так: не идет, почему ?
https://jsfiddle.net/g4jdfo7b/

Comment: В данном примере, 1. не подключен jquery - подключите `jquery`; 2. `visibility: hidden` замените на `display:none` (так как методы `show()` и `hide()` работают с этим свойством `css`)

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_jQuery

Comment: Приведите ваш `fiddle` пример с моими рекомендациями из предпоследнего комментария

Comment: Одну вещь можешь поправить пожалуйста) Когда я выбираю 3й пункт то пусть будут написаны от каждого поля слева "Один", "два", "Три"...
Названия, я поменяю сам этим выше написанным словам))

Comment: Код в ответе вроде так и делает)

Comment: Он берёт эти слова из списка, а мне нужно НЕ из списка, я сам эти слова добавлю, в списке может быть Один Два Три, а мне надо Десять Двадцать Трицать)

Comment: Внес изменения в код ответа

Comment: а вы случайно не знаете ли . как решить мой вопрос тут? ))):
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005598/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-label-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5

Answer (score 0):

```js
var open = [[], [0], [1], [0, 1, 2]];
/* Записываем в массив номера элементов, которые должна открыть каждая опция.
можно было записать для 1, 2, 3, но в JS счет начинается с нуля... привыкайте считать так.
опций всего 4, и первая ничего не открывает (пустой массив). */

var select = document.getElementById('select');
var txt = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
  /* При смене опции, сперва перебираем все инпуты и скрываем всё */
  for( var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++ ){
    txt[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }

  var val = select.selectedIndex; // Находим номер выбранной опции (0, 1, 2, или 3)
  var opentxt = open[val]; // По этому номеру достаем массив чисел из общего массива

  console.clear(); console.log( '(Демо) Получили элемент: [' + opentxt.join(', ') + ']' );

  /* Допустим, получили 4-й массив [0, 1, 2] - перебираем его через цикл 
  и на каждом круге достаем его очередной элемент. opentxt[0] == 0, opentxt[1] == 1...
  этот же элемент, по совместительству, является номером инпута, который нужно показать. */
  for( var i = 0; i < opentxt.length; i++ ){
    txt[opentxt[i]].classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.txt {
  margin: 5px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<input class="txt hidden" placeholder="1...">
<input class="txt hidden" placeholder="2...">
<input class="txt hidden" placeholder="3...">
```