# Сохранить значение label и показать его на другой странице

Tags: php

Прописан label на сайте

```
<label1 id="label12345" name="labelForText">55555</label1>
```

как это значение `55555` перенести на другую страницу и поместить его туда куда надо, или просто на экран вывести ? Вместо `55555` конечно ничего нет, для примера

в начале страница перед html прописано

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

$TextFromWebPage(название переменной ,которую перекинуть на другую страницу)= $_SESSION['здесь надо id или name от лейбла ? '];
```

На другой странице я прописал вот так:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>


<?php echo $_SESSION['$TextFromWebPage']; ?>
```

Почему-то оно не выводиться на экран..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку жизненный цикл переменных в PHP начинается моментом инициализации в скрипте и гарантированно заканчивается с завершением работы скрипта, а отображение страницы - это один проход скрипта, то добрые дяденьки - разработчики языка придумали простой механизм постоянного хранения данных. Это - сессионное хранилище. Устроено оно довольно сложно, но вот пользоваться им - просто. В каждом скрипте с инициализированной сессией оно доступно в виде простого массива с именем $_SESSION. И работать с ним надо - как с самым обычным массивом. Всей разницы - значение никуда не пропадает между запусками различных скриптов (но в рамках одной и той же сессии - это важно!).

Вот рабочий пример Вашего случая.

```
<?php
// script1.php. В нем сохраняем значение в сессионное хранилище.

session_start();

// Инициализируем переменную значением, которое хотим сохранить
$TextFromWebPage = 'Некое значение';

// Что-то делаем еще...

//Сохраняем значение переменной в сессионном хранилище
$_SESSION['уникальный ключ'] = $TextFromWebPage;

?>
```

Если в браузере открыть страницу, сгенерированную этим скриптом, то после своей работы script1.php сохранит в сессионном хранилище значение "Некое значение", доступное в любом другом скрипте через обращение к элементу массива $_SESSION. И если после скрипта script1.php запустить, например, скрипт script2.php

```
<?php

// script2.php - в котором обрабатываем сохраненное ранее значение

session_start();

// Получаем значение из сессионного хранилища. Поскольку открыть эту
// страницу потенциально можно разными путями, а не только после открытия
// script1.php, обрабатываем ситуацию, когда значение может отсутствовать
// (быть неинициализированным ранее)
$TextFromWebPage = $_SESSION['уникальный ключ'] ?? 'Неинициализировано';

// Что-то делаем

// Выводим значение
echo $TextFromWebPage, "\n<br />";

// Так тоже можно, но можно нарваться на ситуацию с неинициализированным
// значением...
echo $_SESSION['уникальный ключ'];

?>
```

то он выведет в браузер 2 раза строку "Некое значение". И это значение будет храниться постоянно в рамках сессии, и доступно будет всегда и из любого скрипта. После использования этого значения его можно и удалить за ненадобностью. Используйте для этого

```
unset($_SESSION['уникальный ключ']);
```

Comment: тоже не пашет((

Comment: Что именно "не пашет"? Оба скрипта перед написанием ответа прогнал в браузере, поведение - как заявлено.

Comment: почитай, пожалуйста, ниже что я написал, после, "пропишу детальнее" 8-)

Comment: Дружище (раз уж ты на "ты" перешел), пожалуйста, попробуй сформулировать свой вопрос одним (максимум - двумя) предложением. Уверен, как только у тебя это получится - ты сможешь получить более конкретные ответы на свой вопрос.

Comment: 1. Как к кнопке привязать три лейбла, один чекбокс, и форму, Причем один из лейблов это строка из базы данных, которая должна попасть в другое текстовое поле после редиректа ?

Comment: 1. Не "к кнопке привязываются три лейбла, один чекбокс и форма", а "создается форма, содержащая 3 лейбла, один чекбокс и кнопку". Если есть кнопка и форма - то кнопка является элементом формы. Начни с простого - создай форму. (http://htmlbook.ru/html/label). (http://htmlbook.ru/html/button)
2. Если значение, которое нужно вывести на второй странице, берется на первой странице из базы данных, то что мешает и на второй странице его из базы достать, а не играться с сессионным хранилищем?
3. Твой вопрос на 90% по HTML, и только 10% - по PHP, и то - не факт.

Comment: 4. Да, и раз уж ты редиректишься с первой страницы - что мешает тебе передать необходимые параметры с первой страницы во вторую в запросе, которым ты редиректишься?

Comment: Ничего не мешает, просто если подгружать из базы то это не проблема, проблема в другом, проблем в том что я нажал кнопку1 (допустим), и к этой кнопке привязаны 3 лейблов, но после нажатия браузер перекидывает меня на другую страницу там есть два поля, в 1ом будет значение из 1го лейбла( а этот лейбл берётся из базы на 1ю страницу) и по аналогии на 2ое поля....но как мне этот лейбл из базы взятых, перенести в поле на вторую страницу я хз..

Comment: Или же просто засунуть этот лейбл в переменную `$Text` и после эту переменную перекинуть на другую страницу..

Comment: Вариант 1. Передай параметром запроса редиректа ID, по которому его достаешь из базы на первой странице, по этому ID выковыряй его на второй странице.
Вариант 2. Передай в запросе само значение.
Вариант 3. Проанализируй исходник первой страницы - возможно, ничего вообще не надо передавать, и так выковырять из базы можно.
Вариант 4. Откажись от редиректа и перепиши всю страницу на ajax-запросы, jQuery в помощь. Тогда javascript'ом сможешь выковыривать прямо из HTML на странице все, что тебе надо, и вставлять в ajax-запросы.
Вариант 5. Закажи решение задачи фрилансеру, подучись на его коде.

Comment: Как передавать параметры в строке запроса - описано здесь (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php). На кнопке submit поставь "правильный" URL на вторую страницу и сразу впиши в него значения, которые надо передать. В скрипте, который формирует вторую страницу, выковыряешь нужные значения из $_GET. P.S. Приличия ради глянул бы самостоятельно хоть одну книжку по PHP...

Comment: все верно наклипал!

Comment: мне другое не понятно, если есть один текстбокс и кнопка возле него, ну к примеру label1 и button1 , чуть ниже , label2 и button2, то если нажать на button1 то он будет нажат вместе с данными от label1...с button2 аналогично

Comment: Мдя... Как все запущено...
Отправка данных формы: http://htmlbook.ru/html/input

Comment: Повесить обработчик на кнопку: http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onclick
Книги, которые стоит прочитать ДО того, как начать задавать вопросы тут: 
1. http://i.uran.ru/webcab/system/files/bookspdf/rnr-7/php.pdf
2. https://site-do.ru/html/
3. http://labs-org.ru/567-2/javascript/
Порядок чтения: (1) по главу 11 включительно, (2), (3), (1) с главы 12 до конца. Разбирать примеры обязательно, на практике, на своем компе - добился работы примера, что-то изменил, посмотрел что поменялось в результате.